# Potentially Flawed Probability Question

Tags: probability

[image: Screenshot]

I stumbled across this question and had to re-read it several times. I looked at the answer key and the answer is listed as A. 
If I'm not mistaken, all of these probabilities have the same chance of occurring, 1/8

Do you guys agree or am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: They all have the same chance of occuring, but that was not the question.

Comment: If they all have an equal chance of occurring, then it is irrelevant which sequence Mo chooses. And I don't see how Ha's choice of HHH affects anything. HHH has the same chance of occurring as THH, THT, ect, so regardless of Mo's choice, his odds of winning will never be greater or worse than Ha's.

Comment: If Ha chooses HHH and Mo chooses THH, then Ha cannot win unless the three *first* tosses are HHH. Otherwise, there is a T before the three HHH, and Mo has won.

Comment: They flip the coin until one of their sequences occurs. If Mo chose HHT, he would in case the first four flips were (if they go on flipping for fun, that doesn't change anything) HHHT, so obviously Ha's choice does mean something.

Comment: Oh, yes. You're absolutely right. Would it be correct to say that if Mo chooses THH that he has a 7/8 chance of winning? Because if Ha doesn't get the initial HHH that she needs on the first 3 flips, then Mo will automatically win somewhere down the line.

Comment: That's correct, yes. It does not fully answer the question, however (you need to prove that the winning probability of all the other sequences are less than $7/8$).

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know if I could prove this rigorously, but I can show that none of the other sequences guarantee victory for Mo if Ha fails to get HHH in the first 3 flips. For example: If Mo chooses THT and the flips occur in the following order: HHTHHH, then Ha wins even after she failed to get the initial HHH. I can do this for the other sequences. So since THH is the only sequence that guarantees Mo's victory after Ha fails to get the initial HHH, it yields the best odds, which is 7/8. Not as good as a rigorous proof, but it works.